# Java Event Dispatch Thread blocked

Tags: java, event-dispatch-thread

I'm trying to change text of `JLabel` during program execution. I know that program execution blocks EDT so I use timer to do this work. But timer starts only after the cycle finishes it's execution although `timer.start()` is located before cycle in source code.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;


@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class TestUpdate extends JFrame {

JLabel lab;
JButton btn;

public TestUpdate() {
    super("Update test");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    btn = new JButton();
    btn.setText("Start test");
    btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Timer tm = new Timer(1, new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    lab.setText("Text is successfully changed");
                    lab.repaint();
                }
            });
            tm.setRepeats(false);
            tm.setInitialDelay(0);
            tm.start();
            long startTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
            while (true) {
                if (System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime >= 3000) break;
                try {Thread.sleep(500);} catch (InterruptedException e1) {}
            }
            lab.setText("Three seconds elapsed");
            btn.setEnabled(false);
        }
    });
    add(btn,"South");

    lab = new JLabel("Should be changed before 3 seconds elapsed");
    lab.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    add(lab);

    setSize(300, 200);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null); 
    setVisible(true);

}



public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
                new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {new TestUpdate(); } });
}

}
```

Comment: You should use a timer for operations you want to delay, and a worker for long operations. It's perfectly OK to do short operations (like changing the content of a field) within the EDT. What you should *never* do is have a `sleep` inside of an event dispatcher.

Comment: If you remove `sleep` from the cycle the effect is the same.

Comment: Did you also remove the endless loop from there?

Comment: Loop is not endless, it lasts 3 seconds. And I want `JLabel` to change it's text before this loop finishes it's execution. Is it possible?

Comment: As I said, you should not perform long operations inside an event loop. That includes sleep, as well as long loops. That's where you are stopping the EDT - not in the changing of the label.

Comment: As I've understood timer (or another thread) will not start until any code execution in EDT comes to it's end. Is it right?

Comment: The timer starts immediately, and fires the event immediately (because you set the initial delay to 0). But then the event is waiting in the event queue. Events are dispatched by the EDT, and since you have blocked the EDT, the event handler will not run until it is unblocked.

Comment: I didn't understand that even `System.out.println` is controlled by EDT. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Not sure which `System.out.println` you are referring to, but any operation is ran by the EDT if it's inside an event dispatcher (e.g. `actionPerformed`, or any other event listener's implementing method) and it runs in a response to an event.

Comment: Re _program execution blocks the EDT_:  That's not right.  The thread that calls your ActionListener _is_ the EDT.  When your listener calls `Thread.sleep()`, it's the EDT that does the sleeping.

Answer (score 0):

Timer event is executed by the EDT, so first event will be executed when current task (your action listener code with `while` loop) will complete. That is why you observe such behaviour.